# PHP - Sort a pre-defined foreach in a custom order

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this simple foreach call that outputs a list of components and is working fine.

```
foreach ($config["components"] as $component_index => $component) {
    echo '<li>$component['name']</li>';
}
```

The issue is however that the values in the foreach loop order are pre-defined and can't be changed but I need to output them in a different order.

Is it possible to re-arrange them into a custom order (That doesn't follow any standard direction, alphabetical, numerical, etc.)

Comment: Take a look at some of these http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Please explain your sorting logic, provide some relevant sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of these http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php,

CUSTOM ordering like, having apple, pear, orange, and wanting them in orange, apple, pear order isn't possible without literally adding them in yourself.

You COULD say...

```
if($component == "thisOne"){ 
      add to array
}elseif($component == "thisOtherOne"{
     add to array
}elseif....
```

From ranking your highest to lowest but that's very inefficient..

Answer (score 0):

As you need a custom sorting algorithm, you can use `usort` function. From what I can see in the question, you don't care about indices, therefore you can do something like this:

```
$components = usort(
    array_values($config['components']),
    function ($a, $b)
    {
        //provide your custom sort function here
        //$a and $b are two "components"
        //for any given pair of $a and $b
        //return -1 if $a should go before $b,
        //return 0 if they are the same
        //return 1 if $a should go after $b
    }
);

foreach ($components as $component) {
    $echo "<li>{$component['name']}</li>";
}
```

Have a look at [`usort` function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for more information.